# history.push using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am navigating from one page to another using history.push which is available from below

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom`

I am able to navigate properly but i have a requirement that if i move from Page A to Page B, i should not be allowed to go back to previous page using Browser back button.

I know this can be achieved by window.redirect but i dont want to use that. The problem with that is the entire state and redux store information is lost. Does anyone know if i can use withRouter and still be able to achieve the requirement above.

Comment: You can use `browserHistory.replace` instead of `browserHistory.push` to remove A from browsing history. That way if user goes to B, he won't be able to go to A, instead go to a URL previous of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `history.replace('/Whatever_screen')` to replace the current page in the stack.

`replace(path, [state]) - (function)` Replaces the current entry on the history stack.

Second option:

You could use the below code to block the user to going back in the history.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
      history.go(1);
    };
  }
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit react-disable-back-button-v1 (forked)]

MDN reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history#Notes):

> There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL.

Comment: Damn. thanks for this function. but issue with this is that all the store and state information is lost

Comment: ok, so you just want to disable the browser back button only a in one  page?

Comment: Yea. is there a way @Sohail Ashraf ?

Comment: yes, let me provide you an working example, give me sometime

Comment: Update the ans, could you please try

Comment: Thank you so much Sohail. i wish i could give this answer more rating. This helps a lot